# JUnit Test For Sorted ArrayList

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

so, I have method:

```
public List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortMap(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            int value = o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            if (value != 0) {
                return value;
            }
            return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
        });
        return list;
    }
```

I need a JUnit test for him. Actually, I started code it, but i dont know how to finish it right

```
       @Test
        public void shouldReturnCurrentList() {
            Object object = new Object();
                List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> testList = new ArrayList<>(testMap.entrySet());
                testMap.put("One", 1);
                testMap.put("Two", 2);
                testMap.put("Three", 3);
                testMap.put("Four", 4);
        
                object.sortMap(testMap); 
}
```

Comment: Invoke the sort on the Map and then verify the expected order against the actual List.  You'll need to contrive a case for matching values with a different key.  You'll need to compare references for that I think.  But given that the method is specific to a Map<String,Integer> there isn't much point to ordering by key so maybe its moot.

Comment: @vsfDawg do I need to loop (for each) through the list at the beginning? could you help me with an example syntax for this test? T_T

Comment: @vsfDawg only this remained in my task and I already broke my brains with this test. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the Map.  In this case I'm adding an element that has a duplicated value.

```
  Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("One", 1);
  map.put("Two", 2);
  map.put("Three", 3);
  map.put("Four", 4);
  map.put("AnotherFour", 4);
```

Now invoke the method

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> actual = SUT.sortMap(map);
```

Now test the order based on how we expect the Map to be processed.  For out map, the order of the keys should be  "One", "Two", "Three", "AnotherFour", "Four" and the order of the values should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 4.

```
Assert.assertEquals("One", actual.get(0).getKey());
Assert.assertEquals(1, actual.get(0).getValue()); 
Assert.assertEquals("Two", actual.get(1).getKey());
Assert.assertEquals(2, actual.get(1).getValue()); 
Assert.assertEquals("Three", actual.get(2).getKey());
Assert.assertEquals(3, actual.get(2).getValue()); 
Assert.assertEquals("AnotherFour", actual.get(3).getKey());
Assert.assertEquals(4, actual.get(3).getValue()); 
Assert.assertEquals("Four", actual.get(4).getKey());
Assert.assertEquals(4, actual.get(4).getValue());
```

Comment: thank you!!! Now I can clearly see what I did not succeed

Comment: @venus upvote answers if they are helpful, so people know which one you have tested and were successful.

Answer (score 0):

There is more convenient way for map.

```
assertThat(testList)
    .contains(Assertions.entry("one", 1), Assertions.entry("two", 2));
```